# CMake / Assembler header .ah file is not visibile

Tags: assembly, cmake

I'm trying to setup Cmake to work with assembler code using qcc compiler from QNX660. Currently .S files are compiling, but the header .ah files are not visible and I get the output:

```
Error: can't open callout.ah for reading: No such file or directory
```

I'm using cmake 3.3 and the current settings are:

```
set(CMAKE_AR "arm-unknown-nto-ar.exe" CACHE FILEPATH "QNX program" FORCE)
set(arch gcc_ntoarmv7le)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER qcc -V${arch} )
set(CMAKE_ASM_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS s;S )
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_C_COMPILER> <DEFINES> -pipe -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a8 -O1 -fomit-frame-pointer <FLAGS> -o <OBJECT> -c <SOURCE>" CACHE STRING "ASM compile command" FORCE )
```

Does someone know what else have to be changed/set? I couldn't find any additional information in the documentation.

Many thanks,
Jarek

Comment: How do you pass list of *include directories* to the compiler? BTW, you can build project with `make VERBOSE=1`, so you can check full compile command being executed.

Comment: I guess, CMake produces output in build dir, which is different from your source dir. Try adding `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)` to the CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Settings for the project are: 
    project(xxx ASM C)
    include_directories( "../public" "../include" "../source" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
   file(GLOB allCodeFiles
    "../include/*.*"
    "../public/*.*"
    "../source/*.*"
)
   add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${allCodeFiles})
The .ah file is located in "public" directory.